# Как убрать нижный бордер у навбара в первом контроллере и показать его на следующем?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

Чтобы убрать "нижний бордер" у navigation bar достаточно в конкретном viewController прописать:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

но как быть, если в следующем viewController нужно этот бордер опять показать? Т.е. в первом контроллере в стеке бордер у топбара должен быть выключен, а в следующих, добавляемых в стек, включен. Можно ли включать/выключать этот "системный бордер"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы говорите о `Shadow` у `UINavigationBar`, то для показа снова достаточно прописать:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

либо установить свою подготовленную картинку (если требуется не просто серая полоска).